# data frame with monthly data to quarterly

Tags: r

I have a data.frame, let us say, mydf, with two columns: date and value.

Example:

```
date    value
2010-01-01  34.5
2010-01-02  21
2010-01-03  31.8
2010-01-04  35
2010-01-05  26
2010-01-06  28
2010-01-07  45
2010-01-08  65
2010-01-09  21
2010-01-10  12
2010-01-11  65
2010-01-12  43
```

The date column is of type character, and the date are monthly dates of format 'yyyy-mm-01'.

The value column is of type float.

How can I transform the monthly values to quarterly values into a new data frame called my.df.quarterly, where the date is also a character of format 'yyyy-mm-01', but it's only during the quarter months of 01 (january), 04 (april), 07 (july) and 10 (October).  And the new values is the sum of the values for each month in the corresponding quarter?

Comment: There are several question on R strategies for collapsing to quarterly sums on SO. You should have done some searching. Don't forget to also search on "season". http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+aggregate+quarterly

Comment: @here most of the answers do lots of transformations and assume ts zoo and other time series related packages, I was wondering if there would be an easy form that also uses the fact that the data format is a character string of format 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Comment: You certainly could extract the 4th and 5th characters with `substr`. and then group, perhaps with a named vector of month values. I'd like to see that you have put some effort into it since both I and @alistaire thought you should have demonstrated more effort and made a better description of the constraints on the problem rather than expecting us to read your mind.

Comment: @Dnaiel You can first convert the dates to 'Date' class and find quarter to which that particular date belongs by `quarters()` function. After that, you will be required to extract the year from the date. Now, using the quarter and year data, you can apply group operation.

Comment: As per @Kunal: quarters(as.Date(mydf$date, "%F"))